# Caching UIWebview from local loaded files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a uiwebview which loads documents from local file system. Some of the images on these HTML files are 2 mb. I wanted to cache those images or the whole HTML.

What is the best way to accomplish or is this even something I should consider?

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Are the images also local to your application? In that case they are already being cached assuming your web view's base url is setup correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your best option would be to cache the large images and put them in the bundle at compile time.  You could then change the URL's to those large images in your HTML to file URL's pointing to the files in the bundle.

Comment: Hey Paul those images are in the local documents directory.

Comment: ahh, I didn't realize that upon my first read of the question.  Is there a certain problem you're experiencing that you feel caching the images in memory will solve?